# I get an "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'phoneNumbers')" when executing a Function in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-functions

I am trying to run the most basic Function using Twilio's Serverless hosted services.  I built this code in the Twilio 'Console -> Functions and Assets' using a sample from their docs (which I pretty much copied verbatim from [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/lookup/v2-api?code-sample=code-basic-lookup-for-a-valid-number&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=4.x#linkcode)):

```
  exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
      const client = context.getTwilioClient();
      client.lookups.v2.phoneNumbers('+14159929960')
        .fetch()
        .then(phone_number => console.log(phone_number.phoneNumber));
  };
```

I made sure that my API credentials are set properly so that they get copied over into the "context" object that is passed down to my Function.  I have also set the Function as publicly accessible.  However, I get the following error when it executes:

{"message":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'phoneNumbers')","name":"TypeError","stack":"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'phoneNumbers')\n at Object.exports.handler (/var/task/handlers/ZNa5464231185aba5ad490f6de6e20b5d0.js:7:21)\n at Object.exports.handler (/var/task/node_modules/runtime-handler/index.js:339:10)\n at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/runtime-handler.js:17:17)\n at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1...

Please help resolve....

Comment: Well, I found the problem.  The Twilio Functions builder in the console does not include v2 api in its dependencies by default.  I had to manually set the 'twilio' dependency to the latest version.

Comment: you're a lifesaver. I was getting confused as why the code was working externally but not within a Twilio serverless function. It doesn't help my live logging isn't working. I recommend adding your comment as an answer and accepting it.